# Hay alguna manera de hacer un select anidado o dependiente usando la plantilla Backpack con laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-for-backpack

Estoy usando la librería backpack para laravel, necesito hacer un select anidado pero no encuentro la manera de hacerlo y en la documentación no encontré una manera de hacerlo, si alguien sabe me puede orientar por favor. muchas gracias

Comment: Yo hice un select anidado de tres niveles, es decir eliges una categoría, de acuerdo a lo que elijas en esa categoría se despliegan las opciones de las subcategorías y de acuedo a lo que elijas en la subcategoría, se despliega otro select dependiente de variantes... La unica forma de hacerlo es con ajax, o vue

Comment: Bro gracias por tu aporte, entiendo que tenga que usar javascript pero como dije en la pregunta estoy usando backpack es una plantilla que maneja todo a su manera.

Comment: Primero bienvenido a stackoverflow, segundo [lee el recorrido](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) para saber como preguntar y ganar tu primera medalla. Tercero "NO importa que plantilla utilices", debes de leer sobre ajax, fetch o axios, cualquiera te ayudara a conseguir lo que deseas y existen otros.

Answer (score 0):

Lo tienes en la documentación, aquí:

https://backpackforlaravel.com/docs/4.1/crud-fields#relationship

Básicamente es crear un tipo de campo `select2_from_ajax` con un atributo que es `dependencies` donde tienes que poner el nombre del `field` del que depende.

También tendrás que usar el atributo `data_source` para obtener el listado filtrado.

De esa manera en cuanto el campo que has puesto en `dependencies` cambie, este campo se reiniciará, apareciendo en el listado los nuevos elementos filtrados.